# Can install ubuntu on my ssd via sata cable?

Tags: ssd

Im replacing my laptop hard drive into ssd. And I was wondering if I can install ubuntu using a sata cable before inserting the ssd into the laptop so that i won't have to use a usb installation anymore.

Comment: You can write and ISO to a hard-drive and use it as if it was a thumb-drive; but the writing of that will erase whatever exists on that drive. You can also write it to a partition, or write it to a *file-system* that exists on a drive, and modify `grub` to offer those options to boot - but for a single-once off install, that's likely more work than just writing to a thumb-drive & using it; in my opinion.  Rather than re-install; are you intended to ask if you can *clone* your *hdd* install to your new *ssd* as that's not how I read your question.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Please explain: Do you want to 1. clone the system from the HDD to the SSD and then insert it into the laptop? 2. make a fresh installation in the SSD? -- If you want to clone the system, you should boot from a third drive, for example a USB pendrive with a live Ubuntu system, for example [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org). If you want to make a fresh installation, it is best to to put the SSD into the laptop or at least remove the HDD from the laptop, and then boot from a USB pendrive with an Ubuntu live system (to be sure to get the bootloader into the SSD).

Comment: If you can connect a SATA data cable to the laptop and a SATA power cable to some suitable power supply (in the laptop or maybe a separate power unit), the SSD will work just like plugged into the computer. Some computers (also some laptops) have an eSATA port where you can connect an eSATA to eSATA or eSATA to SATA cable. But most laptops can only connect one SATA drive. You can still clone: connect the SSD via a USB3 to SATA adapter and a USB pendrive to boot from, and clone from the HDD to the SSD, but it should be faster in a computer with two SATA ports, or one SATA and one eSATA port.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have Ubuntu or another Linux distribution with the GRUB bootloader installed, you can boot the live system from an ISO file by adding an entry to your GRUB configuration. That way, you can boot the installer from the existing hard drive without burning a new DVD or creating a USB drive.

Follow [this guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/196933/how-to-boot-linux-iso-images-directly-from-your-hard-drive/) to add a configuration option to your GRUB 2 bootloader installation. When you boot the ISO, you can then select your SSD, but make sure the bootloader is being installed to the correct drive. However, if your system is EFI, your NVRAM entry will no longer work when the SSD is installed inside the laptop, rather than on the USB bus. You will need to either install the bootloader in 'removable' mode, in which case, the system will boot from the drive automatically without an NVRAM entry, and then correct the boot entry from there, or you need to boot a live system anyway to correct the problem.

The conclusion is, it's probably a lot easier just to create a new live system drive, either on USB or DVD, with the SSD in place in the SATA port, rather than messing around trying to avoid creating one.

Comment: I agree with your conclusion.